# Update original repo from within submodule?

Tags: git

I want to have each of my projects in separate repos, then include them all as submodules within an umbrella repo.

I want to be able to make changes from within the submodule, then push those changes to the original project repo, in addition to the umbrella repo.

Here's my current layout:

```
RepoA/         # "Umbrella" repo to contain the other repos/submodules
    RepoB/
        file1.yml
        file2.yml
    RepoC/
        file3.yml
```

RepoB, and RepoC are each their own repos which are added as submodules under the RepoA repo.

I want to be able to make changes to one of the submodules (say, file1.yml within the RepoB submodule), and have those changes pushed back to the original RepoB repo.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script to group actions together :

- create a commit:

```
# from within the subrepo:
git commit

mymodule=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
git -C /path/to/RepoA add "$mymodule"
git -C /path/to/RepoA commit
```

- push:

```
git push
git -C /path/to/RepoA push
```

`-C path` is one way to say "cd to `path` then run that command"